Как получить пути к конечным точкам дерева из списка списков Python
Я имею многомерный массив
['AA', ['BA', ['CA', ['DA', 'DB']]]]
как получить все пути к конечным точкам
в данном случае их всего два
AA -> BA -> CA -> DA
AA -> BA -> CA -> DB
    AA
    |
    BA
    |
    CA
   / \
  DA  DB


DA и DB можно считать конечной точкой, так как от них больше них точек

в данном случае список не может иметь нулевым элементом список

12
13
14
если следующим элементом после цифры 4, к примеру будет список из [1,2] то конечными путями будут
12 13 141 142

извиняюсь, не совсем верен был в моем сообщении выше.
на самом деле конечными точками будут 12 13, а списка, где последний элемент находится в 1 уровне вложенности не может существовать.
мы можем иметь только
[1, [...]].
элемент, который не имеет списка правее считается конечным, так как он не имеет больше никаких точек, до которых можно достать.
предоставлю часть реального списка
['GIYDMOR', ['RG', ['A5D', ['C', 'E', 'G', 'I', 'K', 'M', 'O'], 'E5D', ['CM', ['A', 'I', 'Q', 'Y']]]]]
к примеру мы можем иметь GIYDMORRGA5DС или GIYDMORRGE5DCMY

Отредактируйте ваш вопрос. Всё то, что вы написали комментариями, добавьте непосредственно в текст вопроса, а комментарии можете удалить. Так будет удобнее.

Список списков есть дерево. Выполните обход дерева, только с пометками придётся чуть по другому работать.
